# use polar coordinates to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} dydx $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} dydx $$ converting to polar coordinates :

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} e^{\sqrt{r^2(cos^2 + sin^2)}} dydx $$
using trig substitution $cos^2 + sin^2 = 1$

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} e^{\sqrt{r^2}} dydx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} e^r drdx  = \int_0^1  e^{\sqrt{1-r^2} } - 1  \space drdx  = e^1 - 1 - e^1 = -1  $$ Is this logic correct ?

Comment: You integrated a positive function over a region and got a negative result. Does that seem reasonable? There are several errors here: You do not have the correct area form for polar coordinates, and you didn't compute the integrals correctly.

Comment: I asked because i was pretty sure it was incorrect please show the correct way instead of just telling me I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In polar coordinates, $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y= r\sin \theta$. Before we compute anything, we need our Jacobian, which tells us the area element for our coordinate system. In this case, we will have $dA = r dr d\theta$. You can verify this by direct calculation.

Now, let's look at the limits. Notice that in $y$ we go from $0$ to $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and then in $x$ we go from $0$ to $1$. So the region is a semi-circle in the top-right quadrant (the limits 'trace out' the blue section in the picture)

[image]

In polar coordinates, that is we go from $0$ to $1$ radially and $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for our angle. So we have $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dydx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^r rd\theta dr$$ Notice there is no $\theta$ dependence in the integral so we can take out the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get $$\frac{\pi}{2} \times \int_0^1 re^r dr = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ That comes from integration by parts, which you can do yourself for verification.

Answer (score 5):

- If you draw that region in the plane you'll see that its the part of the unit disk contained in the first quadrant i.e calling the domain $D$ then $D = \{(r, \theta): 0 \leq r \leq ?, 0 \leq \theta \leq ?\}$. Fill those in.
- Now for the integrand, recall that you just change $x,y$ to their polar form and tac on the $r$ from the jacobian which accounts for the relationship between areas when making the coordinate change i.e,

$$\textbf{Area}= \int_{\theta=?}^{\theta=?} \int_{r=?}^{r=?} e^r \cdot r \ dr \ d\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} dydx $$

Notice that we are finding the region is a quadrant of a circle with radius 1

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{1} r \cdot e^{\sqrt{r^2}} drd\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{1} r \cdot e^r dr d\theta$$

Integrating the inner integral by parts

$$\int r \cdot e^r dr = r \cdot e^r-e^r$$

And from $0$ to $1$, this is $1$

Now our integral is

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 1 d\theta$$

Which clearly evaluates to $\pi/2$

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing to realise is that the integration is over the quarter of the unit circle with both $x$ and $y$ positive. We are told to use polar coordinates $x= r \cos \theta$, $y=\sin \theta $ and $dxdy=r dr d \theta$ and so the integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} dydx = \int_0^{\frac{ \pi}{2}} d \theta \int_0^1 r e^r dr =\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score -1):

What you have is a mess.

you can't say $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$  you need some object.

When you convert to polar coordinates, your coordinate system will be in terms of $r, \theta.\ \ \ dx\ dy$ will be replaced

Start with.

$x = r \cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$

your limits.

$y \le \sqrt {1-x^2}\\
r\sin\theta \le \sqrt {1-r\cos\theta}\\
r^2\sin^2 \theta + r^2\cos^2 \theta le 1$
r le 1$

$y\ge 0\\
r\sin\theta \ge 0\\
\sin\theta \ge 0\\
0\le \theta \le \pi $

$x>0\\
\cos\theta \ge 0\\
0\le \theta \le \frac {\pi}{2} $

The jacobian...
I am not sure I am ready educate you on this.  Look it up.
$dy\ dx = r\ dr\ d\theta$

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^1 re^r \ dr\ d\theta$

$\frac {\pi}{2} (r-1) e^r|_0^1\\
\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: Yes, but the answer is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @MarkFischler first quadrant, thanks.